# Pulsating DC voltage

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, boost, switching

I am working on designing a circuit that generates a pulsating DC voltage into a 50 Ω load.

**EDIT**
Here is the circuit in question, i modified the circuit, I put R6, in order to get the same circuit topology as my booster circuit. Unfortunately that did not solve the problem with the voltage levels.  :[image]

Here is the booster circuit: [image]

The booster circuit generates an output of about 671 V.
[image]

Here is a zoom in:
[image]

The switcher ciruit is supposed to generate a pulsating DC voltage at the output:
[image]

Here is the output of the switching circuit:
[image]

Now when I put both circuits together I see this waveform at the output:
[image]

After adding the 50ohms resistor (R6) here is the new response I get.
The *V_pulse* is the voltage from the mosfet M2, which is supposed to be switching.

[image]

**My question remains :**
I would like to know why the output of the circuit is only at around now 56V. Is there a component that clamps it, or is there something wrong with the topology?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143052/discussion-on-question-by-dimitar-zhekov-pulsating-dc-voltage); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just very basically, you need these:

## Abstract the system

Make a hierarchical diagram of what building blocks are needed.

[image: Block diagram]

This is the simplest version of that.  There are only *single wire connections* between any given block; there are no loops in the graph; the effect of each block on its partner(s) is simply modeled as an RLC equivalent circuit for worst-case purposes; and, despite the nonlinear circuits, no value is obtained from more complex representations than that.  This is therefore an excellent segmentation of the system.

Then we can simulate `HV Supply` on its own.  We can simulate `Pulse Generator` on its own. And we can simulate `Pulse Amplifier` on its own.

So let's simulate the amplifier, that's the most important part.

### Pulse Amplifier

[image: Pulse amplifier basic simulation]

Again, the output network values are somewhat TBD, and no circuit strays have been added; this is just a very basic SPICE model, with an imaginary transistor.

A note: `Id` is `VD[i]` -- it's a common trick to add a (near-zero or zero-value element (such as a voltage source or resistor) in series with a branch you want to measure; LTSpice allows you to just click the branch without doing this.  (I'm using Altium, which is a bit less graceful, at times, when preparing simulations.)

A note, *everything* that is in the SPICE deck is shown graphically here.  There are no hidden parasitic elements or `SUBCKT`s present.  (Beware that many LTSpice elements have default additional parameters.  Please be sure to indicate any such nonzero values on the schematic!)

The waveforms are as below:

[image: Pulse generator waveforms]

The MOSFET model is fairly ideal, so V<sub>DS</sub> saturates to nearly zero, and has no capacitance so the rate is limited by the drive voltage (which is intentionally slow at 8 ns risetime, to somewhat mimic a real one).  The pulse output is mostly the network characteristic, and has about the wave shape required by IEC 61000-4-4 (if not the required source impedance).

Zooming out a bit, we see the specified pulse train (fudged the timing a bit for better visibility):

[image: EFT output]

The tone-burst waveform is neither simulated nor shown here; that's a logic solution to add to `Pulse Generator`.  *Only simulate what you need!*

Note that `Pulse Generator` is simply modeled by `V1` here -- no further circuitry required.  All we need to do for its model, is reproduce the waveform, as wired to a suitable model of the MOSFET gate (which itself hasn't even been modeled here: again, the MOSFET has no capacitances yet).

### HV Supply

The second most important component of the system.  We can approach this many ways.  We could use a single-stage boost from a medium voltage supply (a few hundred V); two (or more) stages from lower voltage (more bother, but has the convenience of running off a DC bench supply); or transformer coupled in any ratio, of which flyback and resonant are the most promising.  And of those, flyback preferably might use multiple secondaries in series, with a rectifier per each, to build up the total desired voltage; resonant is perfectly happy with any kind of rectification, including a voltage multiplier (which is less suitable for flyback due to its capacitive characteristic).

I'll just model a single stage boost for simplicity.

[image: Boost converter]

Note that even the control circuit has been abstracted out as a fixed PWM waveform `V1`.  In general, we want a control circuit here, which could be as crude as a gated-clock (or tone burst, or "hit-or-miss") control, or preferably a current-mode controller (see [UC3842](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua143/slua143.pdf) for example).

The snubber elements (`Rsn`, `Csn`) are added to give some node impedance when MOSFET/diode are off; they are selected for critical damping with a ~50 ns time constant.

And, for sake of illustration, I've gone the extra step and modeled the pulsating load (approximated as a switched resistor of equivalent charge consumption), even though it doesn't add anything -- indeed it makes things harder to see.

The waveforms:

[image: Boost converter waveforms]

Note the inductor peak current is quite large (this is delivering several kW, on average, during the burst!*).  We can use less if we don't require the supply voltage to be maintained during a burst; in that case we would need a much larger `Co` (about 1 µF? -- pretty spicy at 4 kV, but feasible), but merely ~6 W averaged between bursts.

*At the most aggressive (100 kHz repeat rate) level, which is generally recommended for IEC 61000-4-4 testing I believe.  There are 75 pulses in a burst, at 5 or 100 kHz repeat rate, then 300 ms between the start of each burst.

Curiously, though reverse recovery has not been specified, the `SW` waveform shows significant rebound; this seems to be a quirk of SPICE (or maybe of the simulation settings I'm running this at).  In other words, though the diode is "ideal" in terms of parameters, it's still not exactly ideal.

Anyway, notice the stairstep output ripple waveform.  This is the complication of using the pulsed load.  The waves generally interfere, making it harder to measure the ripple output of just the converter itself.  You can however see that the levels are generally similar between cycles, i.e. it's holding constant around 4 kV.  I just calculated this by energy balance, but a control circuit will solve this balance without any precooked numbers.

### Pulse Generator

This is the least interesting block, and also gets rather implementation-dependent.  Notice we could still, at this point, choose a floating / high-side switch configuration, in which case we need an isolated gate driver -- a much more complex bit of hardware, but which adds nothing of general value to the answer.  The least interesting and simplest solution is a [TC4420](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21419D.pdf) or similar gate driver into Si or SiC MOSFET(s) (common source / low-side configuration, or as part of an isolated design).

And as mentioned, we could implement the tone-burst logic at this point, but that is similarly uninteresting: we might simply use a microcontroller to generate the pulses (as well as handle other system functions, like voltage setpoint, or output configuration relays i.e. attenuators, polarity, coupling networks, etc.).

So I will simply conclude here, leaving this as the proverbial *exercise for the reader*, or material for a future question if you like.

Comment: I read your answer 3-4 times and to be honest i am left speachless… I learned more through your answer than any youtube video or any professor i have had( i freshly graduated). Thank you so much